RCLCPP: `get_parameter` as a vector of int (NOT long int/int_64)
I am on ROS2 humble, cpp. I am struggling getting a std::vector<int> as a parameter with the usual declare_parameter and get_parameter, since it seems only the method for std::vector<long> is present.
Indeed, Parameter::as_integer_array() returns a const std::vector<int64_t>, and also in the ParameterValue class, it seems only the int_64 is considered in the ParameterValue::get(), and the constructor as well, when taking a int (not long), costruct the Parameter with type long.
Since I would not like to convert long to int after getting the param, are there any workaround for this?

The ROS 2 parameter data types are listed in the design documentation.
The available types are:
bool
int64
float64
string
byte[]
bool[]
int64[]
float64[]
string[]

So I do not think there is a work around.
What is the exact issue you are facing, that makes you "not want to convert"?
Conversion would just be a matter of assigning the value or doing a cast?
You can use the parameter callbacks to check values for validity before setting the parameter, and reject if necessary. See here for the docs.
Depending on your use case, it might also be relevant to have a look at PickNik Robotics' generate_parameter_library.

ok thanks for the answer. I would like not to convert long to int for eventual overflow problem which will not happen 99% of the case but who knows...
Hence, I imagine is not neither possible to get any kind of std::map as a param right?

I edited my answer to include some references to the parameter callbacks. You could use the on_set_parameters_callback to inspect the upcoming change to the parameters and explicitly reject the change in case of an overflow. std::map is not possible, but maybe you could pass two vectors and implement a an on_set_parameters_callback that validates equal size, and an post_set_parameters_callback that builds the std::map from them?

I also added a reference to generate_parameter_library, could be relevant as well.
